# Lookup without conditional statements

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

This challenge was inspired by programming an Arduino microcontroller. I have 6 LEDs and 6 buttons connected to various pins on the board. In the code, each button and LED is assigned an ID number (1-6). Pin numbers (ranging from 0-13) corresponding to the ID numbers are looked up using a `switch` statement. Purely for amusement, I was wondering if these `switch`es could be circumvented with an arithmetic/other function just to horrify future code maintainers.

### The challenge

Provide the function/functions that take the ID number (integer) as a parameter and return the pin number (integer) for the 6 LEDs and/or the 6 buttons, without using conditional statements (no `if`, no `switch` and no ternary).

Return values for LEDs:

```
ID    Pin
1      3 
2      5
3      6
4      9
5     10
6     11
```

Return values for buttons:

```
ID    Pin
1      2 
2      4
3      7
4      8
5     12
6     13
```

### Bonus challenge

Provide a single function that takes an ID number (integer) and second parameter (any type) indicating whether LED or button pins are requested, and returns the corresponding pin (integer).

### Rules

This is **not** an Arduino-specific challenge. Use **any language**, do **whatever** you want.

Edit: at the suggestion of *steveverril*, this is now a **code golf** challenge.

Good luck!

(If you're still reading: although patently absurd and arbitrary by programming standards, the mappings are based on the Arduino Micro's pinout. Pins 0 and 1 are reserved for serial communication, LEDs are assigned to the 6 lowest-numbered PWM-capable pins, buttons are assigned to remaining pins)

Comment: WeIcome to PPCG! I didn't downvote, but I think this would go better as a codegolf. Popularity contest is very broad in a situation like this. BTW, you can post questions at our sandbox http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599 to have them reviewed prior to posting

Comment: When you say "no if", can I use use a conditional expression as an integer? E.g. `1+(1==1)`?

Comment: Yes, those are fine. Only the three statements mentioned in the challenge (`if`, `switch` and ternary) are off limits.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9282/194)

Comment: @steveverrill thank you for the suggestion, challenge is now code golf. Had I met the reputation requirement of +5 for meta, I would have posted in the Sandbox :) So double thank you for not downvoting a lowly +1 rep casual.

Answer (score 10):

## C, 28 bytes each

```
p(i){return"@cefijk"[i]&15;}
b(i){return"@bdghlm"[i]&15;}
```

This is basically the same as the answer by kirbyfan64sos, but uses a char array instead of integers, and has a dummy first byte so there is no need to subtract 1 from the function parameter.

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 24 bytes each

```
l 1=3
l n=n+l(div(n+2)3)
```

to check:

```
> map l [1..6]
[3,5,6,9,10,11]
```

.

```
b 1=2
b n=n+b(div(n+1)2)
```

to check:

```
> map b [1..6]
[2,4,7,8,12,13]
```

### bonus, Haskell, 36 bytes

```
a f 1=f+2
a f n=n+a f(n+f+1`div`f+2)
```

to check:

```
> map (a 0) [1..6]
[2,4,7,8,12,13]
> map (a 1) [1..6]
[3,5,6,9,10,11]
```

0 for buttons, 1 for LEDs.

Comment: In the bonus, you should be able to use `a f n=n+a f(n+f+div 1f+2)`.

Comment: Yuck! I know it's not in the spirit of codegolf, but this is way too late and too minor to edit a perfectly good solution. Appreciate the attention (to detail) though

Comment: How is it ever too late?

Answer (score 7):

## C (math), 32 / <del>27</del> 26 bytes (45 for bonus challenge)

Several people have posted various table-lookup solutions, but that seemed to me like taking the easy way out.. I wanted to see how well I could do with purely mathematical operations:

```
p(i){return~i&1|i*2^i*!(i%5-1);}
b(i){return i/5*5+1^p(i);}
```

It wasn't clear whether one function calling the other was acceptable or not; if not, one can use this alternate definition of `b(i)` (33 bytes) instead:

```
b(i){return(i&1|i*2)+i/5-!(i/2);}
```

#### Bonus Challenge (45 bytes):

```
f(i,t){return(i&1|i*2)+i/5-!(i/2)^t+i/5*5*t;}
```

(pass `t=0` for buttons, `t=1` for LEDs)

Answer (score 5):

## C, 36 bytes each (49 bytes for the bonus challenge)

```
p(i){return 3500459>>(4*(7+~i))&15;}
b(i){return 2390221>>(4*(7+~i))&15;}
```

<s>I'm sorry...I just couldn't help it...</s> Ok, I put a real solution now.

### Bonus challenge, 49 bytes

```
f(i,t){return(2390221+t*1110238)>>(4*(7+~i))&15;}
```

Use `f(button,0)` and `f(pin,1)`.

[Live demo at Ideone.](http://ideone.com/DGJQHV)

[image: Screenshot]

### Originals:

```
p(i){int a[]={3,5,6,9,10,11};return a[i-1];}
b(i){int a[]={2,4,7,8,12,13};return a[i-1];}
```

Comment: If I wanted sensible answers, I wouldn't be posting in PPCG now would I :P

Interestingly, using this in the actual Arduino program results in a larger size for the compiled binary (which, given ~28K of storage space on the board, is something to be avoided).

Comment: How about `p(i){return"@cefijk"[i]&15;}b(i){return"@bdghlm"[i]&15;}`?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage You should post those as your own answer. They're better than mine is. :)

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Oh ok then

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 12 bytes each

Base encodes the array.

```
@jC"Ý"14tQ (buttons)
@jC"\r'"12tQ (leds)
```

The last one is actually twelve bytes except I can't write a carriage return so i escaped it.

[Test Suite for Buttons](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40jC%22%13%13%C3%9D%2214tQ&input=6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0).

[Test Suite for LEDS](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40jC%22%5Cr%27%13%2212tQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&debug=0).

Comment: I think the OP intended for this to be a function ("Provide the function/functions"); with that it should be trivial to get the bonus: something like `M@jC@"\rÝ"H+12*G2`, which uses 0 for pins and 1 for buttons should work.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, Bonus only: 20 bytes

```
M@jC"5i«$xÍ"16+*6HtG
```

param#2 is 0 for LEDs, 1 for Buttons.  To get Pin# for LED4,`g4 0`

I would have posted this as a comment to Maltysen's entry, but I just started, so lack the required reputation. I've just started using PYTH tonight, and admit that I shamelessly adapted his method of efficiently encoding a list.

If this was inappropriate, my deepest apologies, and I'll remove my entry.

Comment: Hey Brian Tuck! I'm glad you've started using my language. This reuse of Maltysen's idea was probably fine, since base encoding isn't exactly a new idea. Giving credit, which you did, is important, however. By the way, Pyth shouldn't be written in all caps - it's not an acronym, it's just a name.

Answer (score 2):

## MIPS, 16 bytes

Bit shifting and bitmask. Input in `$a0`, output in `$v0`.

```
sll     $t0, $a0, 2 
li      $t1, 0xba96530
srlv    $t0, $t1, $t0   
andi    $v0, $t0, 0xf
```

For bonus, use immediate `0xdc87420`

Comment: Aren't we supposed to count the size of the _source_ when golfing? :)

Answer (score 2):

## F#, 28+28 bytes

I wanted to try this without a lookup table.

```
let L x=1+x*2-x%4/3-x/5-x/6
let B x=x*2+x/3-x/4+x%6/5*2
```

Answer (score 1):

## SWI-Prolog, 34 bytes each

```
l(I,P):-nth1(I,[3,5,6,9,10,11],P).
b(I,P):-nth1(I,[2,4,7,8,12,13],P).
```

`l/2` is for LEDs, `b/2` is for buttons.

#### Bonus, 66 bytes

```
a(I,S,P):-nth1(I,[3:2,5:4,6:7,9:8,10:12,11:13],A:B),(S=0,P=A;P=B).
```

`S = 0` for LEDs, anything else for Buttons.

Answer (score 1):

## q/k (18 bytes each)

Simply a case of indexing:

```
L:0N 3 5 6 9 10 11
B:0N 2 4 1 8 12 13
```

Example:

```
q) L[2]
5
q) B[6]
13
```

### Bonus (1 byte, given L & B defined)

```
@
```

Example:

```
q) @[`L;2]
5
q) @[`B;6]
13
```

Comment: This is deceptively clever use of symbols! +1

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 10 bytes each

These are anonymous functions. The links to the online interpreter show then within a small test harness that executes the function for all input values.

Function 1 (LEDs):

```
{5*3|4+3/}
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=6%2C%3A)%0A%7B5*3%7C4%2B3%2F%7D%0A%25S*)

Function 2 (buttons):

```
{_6|5+*5/}
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=6%2C%3A)%0A%7B_6%7C5%2B*5%2F%7D%0A%25S*)

I wrote a small program that generates and evaluates these expressions. For both of them, it found a number of solutions with 8 characters (counting the expression only without the braces), but none with less.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 26/27 bytes

LEDs:

```
a=>`0   
`.charCodeAt(a)
```

Buttons:

```
a=>`0\r`.charCodeAt(a)
```

If the above doesn't run (which is likely), here's a hexdump:

```
00000000: 6C 3D 61 3D 3E 60 30 03 - 05 06 09 0A 0B 60 2E 63 |l=a=>`0      `.c|
00000010: 68 61 72 43 6F 64 65 41 - 74 28 61 29 0A 62 3D 61 |harCodeAt(a) b=a|
00000020: 3D 3E 60 30 02 04 07 08 - 0C 5C 72 60 2E 63 68 61 |=>`0     \r`.cha|
00000030: 72 43 6F 64 65 41 74 28 - 61 29                   |rCodeAt(a)|
```

I couldn't get the second one to work with a raw CR so I had to use `\r`

#### Bonus, 41 bytes

```
(a,b)=>`0   
\r`.charCodeAt(a+b*6)
```

Hexdump

```
00000000: 28 61 2C 62 29 3D 3E 60 - 30 03 05 06 09 0A 0B 02 |(a,b)=>`0       |
00000010: 04 07 08 0C 5C 72 60 2E - 63 68 61 72 43 6F 64 65 |    \r`.charCode|
00000020: 41 74 28 61 2B 62 2A 36 - 29                      |At(a+b*6)|
```

Second parameter is 0 for LEDs, and 1 for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript <del>113</del> <del>74</del> <del>66</del> <del>59</del> <del>52</del> 33 (one function)

Using bit shift to get 4bit values. Must be called with p(n, 195650864 or 231240736).

```
/*
  11   10    9    6    5    3
1011 1010 1001 0110 0101 0011 0000 = 195650864

  13   12    8    7    4    2
1101 1100 1000 0111 0100 0010 0000 = 231240736

                   b >> i * 4 xxxx
                         & 15 1111
                              yyyy (matching 1s)
*/
// Where b = 195650864 for pins and 231240736 for buttons.
function p(i,b){return b>>i*4&15}
```

Alternate.

```
/*
Using bitwise * 4 for bitwise only.    
function p(i,b){return b>>(i<<2)&15}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainf**k, 107 bytes

```
,>++++++++[>+>++++++<<-<------>]<[>+++<-[>++<-[>+<-[>+++<-[>>>+>+<<<[-]+<-]]]]]>>[<++++++>-]<.>>>[-[-]<-.>]
```

This being my first hand-coded BF program, I don't doubt that there are several optimizations to be made. But it's still awesome. :)

I'm not sure if `[]` counts as a conditional, though... :/

Comment: We have [a challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16732/minify-brainfuck) full of BF optimisers at your disposal if you wanted to use one ;)

Comment: @BetaDecay They look great, but none of them actually make my code any shorter... :/

Comment: Hm, that's a shame :P

Answer (score 0):

#### POWERSHELL - 27-27-72

**LED use 1..6 as args**

```
:\>wc -c LED.PS1 & cat LED.PS1 & echo.& powershell -nologo -f LED.PS1 1
27 LED.PS1
(0,3,5,6,9,10,11)[$args[0]]
3
```

**button use 1..6 as args**

```
:\>wc -c button.PS1 & cat button.PS1 & echo.& powershell -nologo -f button.PS1 6    
27 button.PS1
(0,2,4,7,8,12,13)[$args[0]]
13
```

**LED or BUTTON use b 1 ; l 2 ; b 6 ; l 5 etc as args**

```
:\>wc -c ledbutt.PS1 & cat ledbutt.PS1 & echo.& powershell -nologo -f ledbutt.PS1 b 5
72 ledbutt.PS1
$a=@{"b"=(0,3,5,6,9,10,11);"l"=(0,2,4,7,8,12,13)};$a[$args[0]][$args[1]]
10
:\>powershell -nologo -f ledbutt.PS1 l 5
12    
:\>powershell -nologo -f ledbutt.PS1 b 3
6    
:\>powershell -nologo -f ledbutt.PS1 l 2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

## Octave, 40 bytes (bonus challenge)

Using an anonuymous function:

```
@(x,y)[3 2;5 4;6 7;9 8;10 12;11 13](x,y)
```

After defining this function, call this function as `ans(x,y)`, where `x` is the pin/button number and `y` indicates pin or button with values `1` and `2` respectively.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/U0c8O5)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript(ES6) 18,22,44

**Edit** Shorter but boring

```js
// LED 
l=i=>1-~' 134789'[i]
// Buttons
b=i=>[,2,4,7,8,12,13][i]

// bonus
f=(i,t)=>1-~[' 134789',[,0,2,5,6,10,11]][t][i]

//Test

out=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

for(i=1;i<=6;i++) out(i +' -> '+l(i) + ' '+b(i) +' '+f(i,0)+' '+f(i,1))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 4 (37 and 31 bytes)

LEDs (37 bytes):

```
$c=pop;$c*2+($c~~[1,2,4,6]&&5.5<=>$c)
```

... but it uses a lookup table.

Buttons (31 bytes, no lookup):

```
$c=pop;2*($c+($c==5))+($c%3==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 31 Bytes Each

Not exactly creative or anything, but it works!

```py
l=lambda x:int(" 3569AB"[x],16)
b=lambda x:int(" 2478CD"[x],16)
```

## Bonus, 44 Bytes

```py
k=lambda x,y:int("3569AB2478CD"[x-1+6*y],16)
```

`y` should be 0 for LEDs, and 1 for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 60 + 58 = 118 bytes

```
p=lambda i:(2**i)*(i<3)+1+(i>2)*(5+3*(i-3))-(i>4)*(i-3+~i%2)
b=lambda i:2**i-(i>2)-(i>3)*(2**(i-1)-1)-4*(i>4)-15*(i==6)
```

These are awful. i don't even know what I'm doing here...

But they're pretty interesting nonetheless! :D

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 45 Bytes

```
->i,t{[3,5,6,9,10,11,2,4,7,8,12,13][t*6+i-1]}
```

## Test Inputs:

```
->i,t{[3,5,6,9,10,11,2,4,7,8,12,13][t*6+i-1]}.call 1,0
=> 3

->i,t{[3,5,6,9,10,11,2,4,7,8,12,13][t*6+i-1]}.call 3,1
=> 7
```

Answer (score 0):

## Forth, 26 bytes each, 34 for bonus

Similar to the C version by squeamish.

```
: P " CEFIJK" + C@ F AND ;
: B " BDGHLM" + C@ F AND ;
```

Bonus:

```
: A " CEFIJKBDGHLM" + + C@ F AND ;
```

Use 0 for LEDs and 6 for buttons. And the parameter order doesn't matter

Answer (score -1):

## Pyth, 19 bytes each

```
L.&.>3500459*4-6b15
L.&.>2390221*4-6b15
```

For pins and buttons, respectively.